# Why CLONE and NEW which are Operators of equal precedence that are non-associative work next to each other?

Tags: php, operators

In the PHP documentation, it says: [Operators of equal precedence that are non-associative cannot be used next to each other, for example `1 < 2 > 1` is illegal in PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

However, this seems to work even though `clone` and `new` are of equal precedence and are non-associative:

```
var_dump(clone new stdClass()); // output: object(stdClass)#2 (0) {}
```

Why is this possible?

Comment: **Because nobody in their right mind would write that line of code. EVER!** Why `clone` a `new object` and not just `new` it? You `clone` a modified object, not a brand `new` instance.

Comment: Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do __not__ specify an order of evaluation.